# strange behaviour of navigation bar buttons in iOS?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

[image]

I had an application where i am using `imagePickerController` and action viewcontroler,Everything working fine except navigation bar buttons position, I am working on iOS 8.4 on both these cases I was just presenting the view controller, but the bar buttons seems to be just off the screen layout.